# Which relationship model to use for storing a value that depends on other values?

Tags: mysql, sql

The task that I have got:

Implement Product Discount functionality, where the amount of Discount depends on different conditions, for example:

1. Amount of Discount depends on Product Category (Phone, TV, PC);
2. Amount of Discount depends on Product Manufacturer (Apple, Samsung, Sony);
3. Amount of Discount depends on Customer Type (Registered/Guest);
4. etc.

Assume, that we need to cover only first condition, where the Discount amount per Manufacturer -  I think this is a pure example of 1 to 1 relationship, where for each Manufacturer defined their own discount.

From the DB schema point of view, we can easily implement this part in 2 ways:

1. One Table MANUFACTURER_DISCOUNT with 2 Columns: MANUFACTURER_NAME (type ENUM) and DISCOUNT_AMOUNT (type: LONG);
2. Or with 2 Tables MANUFACTURER (MANUFACTURER_NAME, ID) and DISCOUNT (DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, MANUFACTURER_ID);

But what I have to do in the case when I have more than 1 criteria (discount per manufacturer) only?

How can I properly build the structure of my tables?

- Do I need just to extend the table that I described as option 1 with additional columns like PRODUCT_CATECORY, CUSTOMER_TYPE or possible more elegant and correct solution exists?

Answer (score 0):

Each discount should be its own table.

Then the amount of discount query becomes something like:

```
SELECT IFNULL(cd.discount, 0) + IFNULL(md.discount, 0) + IFNULL(custd.discount, 0) as discount
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN category_discount cd
 ON p.category = cd.category
LEFT JOIN manufacturer_discount md
 ON p.manufacturer = md.manufacturer
LEFT JOIN customer_discount custd
 ON p.customer_type = custd.customer_type
```

Note the `JOIN`s are more important here than the exact calculation on the discount, just remember NULL is a not found value and need to be accounted for.

Keep tables for a single purpose. Putting multiple discount types could just get messy as you'd need multiple rows. Multiple tables with one to one relationships also end up being an unnecessary complication.

When in doubt about table structures, start to write out the queries you need on those tables. It usually becomes obvious which table structure results in simple queries at that point.